# How can I modify a CCK fields display via a module?

Tags: drupal, module, hook, cck

I'm working on a drupal module, and one thing that it needs to do is modify the display of cck file fields automatically (using template files is not an option).  For example, this array:

```
$node->field_images[0]['view'];
```

That is what I would like to get into.  The 'view' part will output an image based on the display settings for the content type.  I would like to attach a link to each image before the node is displayed to the user.

One thing I've tried:

```
function mymodule_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $teaser, $page) {
      switch ($op) {
          case 'view':
            $node->content['field_images']['view'] = array(
              '#value' => "hello",
              '#weight' => 10
            );
          break;
      }
 }
```

This inserts the text one time after the last image.  I tried using a foreach to loop through all of them and produced no results at all.

I've also tried this:

```
function mymodule_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $teaser, $page) {
      switch ($op) {
          case 'view':
              // Attach link           
              foreach($node->field_images as $media) {
                  $media['view'] .= generate_link($node->nid, $media);
              }           
          break;
      }
    }
```

It seems like it should work, but it doesn't.  I've searched everywhere for solutions without any luck.

If someone could help me out I would really appreciate it.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you ever resolved this? I've run into the same issue. Ideally, it should be done via hook_field(), but it's only available in Drupal 7.

Answer (score 1):

#### Edit

To modify the CCK values before the page is loaded *outside* the templating system, use the `alter` op in `hook_nodeapi`. `view` is called before the node is rendered, `alter` is called after.

---

As you noticed, the CCK fields are not populated in time for the places you're trying to put code. Instead, you need to use a preprocessing function—[`template_preprocess_node()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/template_preprocess_node)—which will let you modify values just before the rendered output is displayed.

```
function mymodule_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  // $variables['field_name'] contains the CCK array for field_name
}
```

This won't change the rendered output of `$content` in your node template (unless you really want to get into resetting `$variables['content']`, but it will allow you to use `$field_name` in your template with your preprocessed values.

Alternatively, you could create your own custom formatter for the field, which *will* affect the rendered output of `$content`. Check out [googletorp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/127549/googletorp)'s blog post on [Creating a field formatter for CCK](http://googletorp.com/2009/nov/24/creating-field-formatter-cck/).

Comment: I'm not sure this will work since preprocessing a node only makes the variables available to template files.  I don't have the option to use template files. This module needs to automatically generate and attach the links to each filefield once its enabled.  Isn't hook_nodeapi the only way to do that?